# IIFE Parameters vs Declaration

Tags: javascript

Are there reasons for creating variables as undefined parameters instead of declaring them using var or let?

```
(function (a, b, c, d, e) {
     c = b.createEleement('a');
     d = b.getElementsByTagName('div');
     e = a.outerWidth;
})(window, document)


(function (a, b) {
    var c = b.createEleement('a'),
        d = b.getElementsByTagName('div'),
        e = a.outerWidth;
})(window, document)
```

Comment: Not really, it just saves a couple of characters.

Answer (score 2):

It's a technique employed by minifiers to save the `var` keyword if there already is an IIFE.

There is no good reason to write source code like this, it's confusing.